# How to free a two dimensional array using malloc

Tags: c

I have a array that has 6 elements. And each of those 6 elements have 40 elements. I am wondering when i free the malloced memory, do I have to free both or can i just free the main layer ( the one containing the 6 elements) will this automatically free the other secondary array?

```
 char ** listofdetails;  //FIRST ARRAY
    listofdetails = malloc(sizeof(char*)*6);

    for(i=0;i<6;i++)
    {
    listofdetails[i] = malloc(sizeof(char)*40); // SECONDARY ARRAY
    fgets(listofdetails[i], 40, fp);
    }
```

Comment: Free both layers: one `free()` call for each `malloc()` call.

Comment: Every call to `malloc` must be paired with a call to `free` to release the allocated memory.

Comment: Don't write `sizeof(char)`, it makes you look illiterate. It's always 1.

Comment: This is not a 2D array. Try to allocate a real one. `char (*array)[40] = malloc(sizeof(char[6][40]));`

Answer (score 4):

You need a destroying function like

```
 void destroy_array_of_cstrings (char**lis, size_t siz)
 {
    if (!lis) return;
    for (size_t ix=0; ix<siz; ix++) free (lis[ix]);
    free (lis);
 }
```

You'll call `destroy_array_cstring(listofdetails, 6)` in *your* case. As [Alfred Hang answered](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2674217/alfred-huang), you should clear `listofdetails` immediately after: `listofdetails=NULL;` to avoid accidentally `free`-ing a pointer twice, or dereferencing a freed pointer.

You'll better use `calloc` for allocation of an array of pointers (you really want each of them to be initialized to `NULL`, which `calloc` does in practice).

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25313892/841108) to a question also mentionning `listeofdetails` with 6 (so I guess it is the *same* homework).

BTW, you might later use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/): you would use `GC_MALLOC`, `GC_STRDUP` and you won't bother about free-ing anymore. Discuss that with your teacher.

Answer (score 3):

Rule of thumb: for every malloc there is a free.

You have to provide a similar loop where you free each individual string before freeing the array of strings.

Comment: This might be more of a commandment than a rule of thumb.  It's a programming sin to ignore it.

Comment: @AShelly: Unless it's a sin to do it: There's no sense in sweeping the floors if you called in the wrecking crew!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Basile's answer, to avoid having dangling pointers after you free each array entry, it is a good idea to immediately set the pointer to null.

Reference: [free()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

Answer (score 1):

No, the secondary arrays will not be freed automatically; you will need to explicitly `free` them *before* freeing `listofdetails`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
  free( listofdetails[i] );
free( listofdetails );
```

For every `malloc` there must be a `free`, and the `free` calls must be executed in the reverse order of the `malloc` calls.

If the number of columns is known at compile time<sup>1</sup>, you can allocate the whole thing in one `malloc` call, like so:

```
char (*listofdetails)[40] = malloc( sizeof *listofdetails * 6 );
```

This allocates a 6x40 array of `char` in a single call.  You'd use it pretty much the same way as you do above:

```
fgets( listofdetails[i], sizeof listofdetails[i], fp );
```

The type of `listdetails[i]` is "40-element array of `char`", so `sizeof listdetails[i]` will give us the same result as `sizeof (char) * 40` (note that this *only* works because I declared `listofdetails` as a pointer to a 40-element array of `char`, not as a pointer to a pointer to `char`).

This also has the advantage that all of the rows are adjacent to each other in memory, which may matter for some situations.  That's not necessarily the case for the 2-step allocation method.

This only requires a single `free` call:

```
free( listofdetails );
```

but y'all probably aren't to the point of discussing pointers to arrays yet.

---

1.  If you're using a C99 compiler or a C2011 compiler that still supports variable-length arrays, you can still use the single `malloc` call like so:

```
size_t rows, cols;
...
char (*listofdetails[cols]) = malloc( sizeof *listofdetails * rows );
...
free( listofdetails );
```

Otherwise, you'll have to do the piecemeal allocation as in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access `listofdetails[i][j]` like this, then yes, you will need to malloc the internal array. And you will have to free it separately too.

If you know the inner array size and it is fixed for all, then you can alloc everything up front (width * height) and access it like this: `listofdetails[i * width + j]`

Answer (score 0):

After dynamically allocating memory for this aaray when it comes time to free one of these dynamically allocated multidimensional ``arrays,'' we must remember to free each of the chunks of memory that we've allocated. (Just freeing the top-level pointer, array, wouldn't cut it; if we did, all the second-level pointers would be lost but not freed, and would waste memory.) Here's what the code might look like:

```
for(i = 0; i < nrows; i++)
    free(array[i]);
free(array);
```

For your case it should be  :

```
for ( i = 0; i < 6; i++ )
  free( listofdetails[i] );
free( listofdetails );
```