# How can a function create a struct?

Tags: c, struct

One of my assignments for the C Programming course was define a function called create_card. This function receives a suit character and an a card value, and returns a card_t struct.

Question: How is a function supposed to create a struct? Can't it only create values for the struct? Did I misinterpret the meaning of the question or was the assignment written down wrong?

Comment: would help if you post code

Comment: I don't have any code. It's an assignment. They give you parameters to follow and you have to design it yourself.

Comment: Are you perhaps lost in linguistics? The function can not create a type (and hey, a struct is a type, so  creating a struct means creating a type, right?) -- that's still something the programmer must do, in statically typed languages like C. It can create *objects* of certain types though, and that is probably the meaning of this in the pesky natural language we use.

Comment: I wrote it verbatim as it was written on the assignment. I didn't know if the assignment had a typo or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of a function returning a struct.

```
struct test {
    int a;
};
struct test Fun(int k) {
    struct test d;
    d.a=k;
    return d;
}
```

Replace `struct test` with the name of your struct and the definition of `struct test` with your struct's definition.

How to use

```
int main() {
    struct test Test=Fun(6);
    printf("%d",Test.a); // prints '6'
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks ForceBru

Answer (score -1):

You can either *return* a `struct` from a function like in [ForceBru's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804568/841108), or you can *create* a `struct` in [C dynamic memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation) (a.k.a. the heap), using `malloc`, and return a pointer to it, e.g.

```
struct foo_st {
  int num;
  const char* str;
};

struct foo_st* 
/* the second argument s should practically be a literal string */
make_foo (int n, const char* s) {
   struct foo_st* p = malloc(sizeof(struct foo_st));
   if (!p) { perror("malloc foo"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
   p->num = n;
   p->str = s;
   return p;
}
```

Your `main` (or some other function) might later do `struct foo_st*fooptr = make_foo(32, "abc");` but someone should call `free(fooptr)` (or at least, `free` the address which has been inside `fooptr`).

Of course, you should never forget to `free` a `malloc`-ed pointer when it becomes useless. Be afraid of [memory leaks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), [buffer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and [undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Read more about [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) & `free`.

BTW, in practice you should decide of who is responsible for `free`-ing memory. In the above `make_foo` example, the second parameter to `make_foo` is supposed to be a literal string (if it is `malloc`-ed e.g. using [strdup(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strdup.3.html), you'll need to `free` it elsewhere, and that becomes very messy).

In practice you should *document the conventions about **who is responsible** to `free`* some dynamically previously `malloc`ated memory. You might want to use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (if your system has it), and, if using a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler, its [-fsanitize=address option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16747187/841108) to hunt memory related bugs. Very often, you happen to code both making and destroying functions (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25365945/841108) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23433573/841108)).

You might want to read about [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) (at least, to understand the concepts, such as [reference counting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting), and the terminology). Perhaps you'll later want to use [Boehm's conservative garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/).

Comment: Don't forget to `free(fooptr);` when it's not needed anymore.

Comment: A literal string is a constant array of bytes, terminated by a zero byte. Arrays are *decaying* into pointers.