# The hashtag in #include <stdio.h> does not compile (C-programming)

Tags: c, header, syntax-error

I made my first program in C without any problems at all at my first try, now that I want a new workspace and a new project, it goes south before I've even written anything.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The code above should just print out "hello world". Instead, I get the following error code:

```
C:\Users\DavidH\Desktop\bingolotto\main.c:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { #include <stdio.
                                                              ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:73:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:443:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
Press any key to continue . . .
```

I'm guessing I've got some faulty directories or something similar, but I've made new workspaces and tried at least two new projects to no prevail.

I'd really like to know what's going on here :)

Comment: Wait! Can you post the command how are you compiling the code and running the code?

Comment: Looks like you're trying to "run" C code with node.js?

Comment: "*The hashtag in #include <stdio.h> ...*" why am I feeling so old?

Comment: The references to `node.js` are the biggest red flag here. Are you just trying to execute the .c file as if it were a script?

Comment: It is true that my workspace is node.js. I chose it according to my tutor's instructions . My other two options are C++ and PHP, can C code compile in any of those?

Comment: Some C++ compilers have options to compile C code.

Comment: Wait, your tutor wants you to use node.js and you write C code? What... Your tutor expects you to write JavaScript, I guess.

Comment: @DavidHermansson Then you need to have a very strong word with your tutor.

Comment: If your instructor told you to build C code with Node.js, you are being scammed. Demand your money back for the course.

Comment: Maybe I've missed some correction, but I know that my classmates have the same three options and it's working fine for them(node.js, C++, PHP)

Comment: it's a tutor at Chalmers Uni in Sweden, so I don't pay him a dime. I must have missed something, but thanks for enlightening me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You practically need to use a C [compiler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) (not something else like [node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)). I recommend using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) on the command line, e.g. in a terminal (order of program arguments to `gcc` matters a lot). And I recommend enabling all warnings and debug info (which are not enabled by default), so compile [with](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html):

```
 gcc -Wall -Wextra -g helloworld.c -o helloworld.exe
```

Improve your code to get no warnings at all.

Read the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c) of every used function (e.g. of [printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)), even if at first you don't understand all of it. Download the specification of [C11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision)), e.g. [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), and look inside and refer to it.

Be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). It is tricky (your C program could apparently seem to work most of the time, and still be very wrong and buggy).

Learn to use the debugger, e.g. [use `gdb`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) (and perhaps other tools, like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)).

You probably should learn to use some [version control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_control) system (I recommend [git](http://git-scm.com/)) and some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool (such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/)).

Be aware that coding conventions and style matter a lot in C (see for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29804646/841108)).

PS. You might consider installing some [Linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_distribution) on your laptop, it is very student- and developer- friendly and mostly made of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (some very helpful to novice and/or expert C developers, both as tools and as examples). You also should read (for inspiration) the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (e.g. on [github](http://github.com/)).

Comment: I use gcc template, minGW complier and GNU debugger. I added those lines you recommended and it worked perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I do recommend installing Linux on your laptop.

Comment: debugger and git is something I grew fond of during my C# lectures, I just need some time to get to know C
Haven't got a laptop, but I already have a linux environment installed

Comment: What has Linux got to do with anything? "Developer friendly" ...yeah right. I have barely touched Linux in 15 years and I work pretty much exclusively with C programming. Please keep advise objective. Tool recommendations are also off-topic here.

Comment: Linux has most of its programs as free software in C, so people can glance into them. The C standard library and the Linux kernel is also free software (unlike on Windows), and you can also look into it. And `valgrind` works well on Linux (but perhaps not on Windows).