# Should I delete pointers that come from other functions or class methods?

Tags: c++, pointers, posix, heap-memory

I have a background in Java and I'm still not fully used to the concept of pointers and scope, so sorry if the question seems silly.

I read somewhere that I should delete pointers that I have allocated on the Heap. I understand that but should I also delete a pointer that is given to me like this:

```
#include<dirent.h>

DIR* dir;
struct dirent* entries;

dir= opendir("D:/DIR")
entries= readdir(entries)

// Should I delete the pointers after I'm done with them?
delete entries;
delete dir;
```

Should I delete the pointers which are assigned from somewhere else or just going out of scope deletes them automatically?

Or is it even right to delete them since I haven't assigned them using `new`? But then if it's wrong how can I make sure that the memory assigned from the other methods would be deleted after I'm finished using them?

Comment: You need to read the documentation for each and every function.  Where is `#include<dirent.h>` from it's not standard `C++` or `C`?

Comment: You `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. And you should never `delete` anything that was not allocated with `new`, like for example memory allocated with `malloc`. And as noted in e.g. [this `readdir` manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/readdir.html) you should *not* `free` the returned pointer. Neither should you free the pointer returned by `opendir`, instead you should *close* it like a file, with `closedir`. Any example on the web should have told you that.

Comment: And in the future, please don't spam with language tag. Only use the language you actually program in. In your case it should be the `c++` tag only.

Comment: In this case, these pointers are allocated automatically by the function calls, so you do not need to delete them or worry about, but you must call the respective close functions, for example `closedir()`. Also, if you check `man readdir` it states that you should not free a pointer returned by this function call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C is not the same as C++, notably for this aspect.

When using some external C (or C++) function provided by some external library, you should **read its documentation** and **follow** the "ownership" rules and ***conventions***. For example if you use [`getline`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) you understand that you need to `free` like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25313892/841108).  If you use [`opendir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) you should use [`closedir`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/closedir.3.html). If you use [`sqlite3_prepare_v2`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html) you'll need to [`sqlite3_finalize`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/finalize.html) it, etc... Sometimes you'll think in terms of some [abstract data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) (like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47235897/841108)) with a [destructor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Destructor_(computer_programming))-like function.

When you *develop* your own (public or "private") function in C, you need to *document* if it returns heap allocated memory and who (and how) is responsible of `free` (or releasing) it.

With C++, you also have [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory) and [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization); so you generally can avoid manual `new` and `delete`. Smart pointers are helpful, but [not a silver bullet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_Silver_Bullet).

So **you should *explicit* and *document* conventions** (and follow the conventions of external libraries and APIs) about ownership. Understanding and defining wisely such conventions is an important task.

[Circular references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reference) are difficult to handle (consider [weak pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_reference) when applicable). I recommend reading about garbage collection concepts and techniques (e.g. the [*GC handbook*](http://gchandbook.org/)), to at least be able to name appropriately your approaches and understand the limitations and power of [reference counting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting). In *some* cases, you might even explicitly use a [garbage collector library](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7909164/841108) or code your own allocator.

[Manual memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manual_memory_management) is a whole program property, and that is why it is hard. There are even cases (long-living processes doing a lot of allocation) where you need to be afraid of [fragmentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_(computing)).

Tools like [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and the [address sanitizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AddressSanitizer) (with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)'s [instrumentation options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) or [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)'s ones) are practically very helpful to hunt [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and some other memory bugs. Be also aware of [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). Take care to understand the [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) of your [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing)). On Linux, read [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) then try `cat /proc/$$/maps` and `cat /proc/self/maps` in some terminal for a useful insight.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.

The unavoidable rule in C++ is that every `new` needs to be paired with a `delete`, and every `new[]` with a `delete[]`, and that `malloc`, `free`, &c. are still available.

So it's tempting to suppose that the memory you get back from `readdir` is required to be released with an explicit call to `delete`, but that *might* not be the case:

1. It might have been allocated with a `new[]`, or even, `malloc`!
2. The library might provide a function that you need to call that releases the memory.
3. If the library has a persuasion to working well with the C++ standard library, it might provide you with a *deleter*: which you can pass on construction to a *smart pointer* such as `std::unique_ptr`.

I think that (2) is most likely and is the most sensible since different C++ runtime environments might perform `new` and `delete` differently. (3) is an extension to this concept and if they support it then use that.

The golden rule is to **check the documentation** and do what it tells you.

Answer (score 4):

There's no definitive answer to the question, because it *always* depends on the semantics by which the memory was allocated. For example in the very code example you gave, you *must* not use `delete` for deallocation, because `opendir` is not a C++ function (but a POSIX one) and to properly close it you call `closedir`. The pointer itself then can be discarded (no deletion requierd, `closedir` internally does the cleanup). Just make sure you don't use it after free (see: use-after-free-bug).

In general you always have to consult the manual of the function that gives you a pointer, where it's also specified exactly how to deallocate it.

Just to give you the idea:

- malloc/calloc/realloc → free
- fopen → fclose
- X… → XFree

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you should consult the vendor's manual and see if their functions do the cleaning themselves or you need to call another function to do the cleaning etc. In general when talking about *raw* pointers in C++ you should explicitly release the allocated memory where appropriate. Whether it comes from a function or a `new` / `new[]` operator does not make a difference. To avoid this `new` / `delete` combination you can utilize [smart pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/memory) and the [RAII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/raii) technique.