# Why delete wchar_t pointer crashes?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm wondering what happens to wchar_t* pointer after being used by WM_SETTEXT.

```
wchar_t* f = L"test1";
    wchar_t* f2 = L"test2";
    SendMessage(hWndEdit1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)f);
    // after some operations 
    SendMessage(hWndEdit1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)f2);
    delete f; // crashes
```

Why **delete f;** crashes?

Comment: Why do you think you could delete something, that was never new'd?

Comment: You `delete` what you `new`, and `delete[]` what you `new[]`. If you haven't allocated anything with `new` or `new[]`, then you should not `delete` or `delete[]` it.

Comment: You also should avoid discarding `const` even if your compiler tries to let you. A literal like `L"test1"` is `const` so `f` and `f2` should also be `const`.

Comment: A similar question asked recently: [Should I delete pointers that come from other functions or class methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151025/shoud-i-delete-pointers-that-come-from-other-functions-or-class-methods)

Comment: When you pass a pointer through the `WM_SETTEXT` message, the system makes a copy of the contents. You can dispose of the pointee as soon as the `SendMessage` call returns. In this case, you are holding a pointer to a character array. The lifetime is controlled by the compiler; you need not do anything to clean up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove this statement:

```
delete f; // crashes
```

You are causing [undefined behavior](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) by calling the [delete](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_delete) operator on a pointer that was **not** [new](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new)-ed. You should only `delete` what you `new`-ed and `delete[]` what you `new[]`-ed. Excerpt from the **n4140** draft, paragraph **5.3.5.2**:

> the value of the operand of delete may be a null pointer value, a
>   pointer to a non-array object created by a previous new-expression, or
>   a pointer to a subobject (1.8) representing a base class of such an
>   object (Clause 10). If not, the behavior is undefined

Note that in standard C++ you should apply a `const` qualifier when using pointers to string literals:

```
const wchar_t* f = L"test";
```

Or even better use the wide string:

```
std::wstring ws = L"test";
```

Comment: doesn't it occupy memory on ram? So aren't we have to delete?

Comment: Sure, it occupies memory.   But you can only `delete` something that was allocated using operator `new`.       Using `delete` on anything else doesn't work.   Why?   Because that's that the C++ standard specifies.

Comment: You may find this helpful... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36646493/c-stack-vs-heap-allocation

Comment: @Peter, If so, automatically deallocate at the end of the scope?

Comment: No. It doesn't. Typically the memory for those literals will be static and deallocated when the program terminates. They were allocated when the program started.

Comment: @Mesut: [String literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) have static storage duration. They live for the entire lifetime of your program.

Comment: I'd like to allocate new pointer with "new" for wchar_t array and "delete" after SendMessage(). How to do this according to my sample?

Comment: @Mesut: Don't. Use a `std::wstring` instead: `std::wstring ws{ L"test" }; ::SendMessage( hWndEdit1, WM_SETTEXT, 0, (LPARAM)ws.c_str() );`. There is no reason to use `operator new` and `operator delete` in C++. Why do you want to resort to manual memory management?

Comment: @IInspectable: 1. I think that wchar_t is faster than std::wstring. I'll perform long long operations. 2. I'll compile my dll for both windows and linux and want to be used by C++ core functions not by extended libraries. Am I wrong?

Comment: @Mesut: Yes, you are wrong. The expensive operation is `operator new`. It doesn't matter, whether you use a raw array, or `std::wstring`, where the latter can actually be faster in subsequent operations, because it doesn't have to calculate the string length. Don't neglect the first rule of performance optimization: Do not make any assumptions. Profile your code instead. I'm not sure what your second point is supposed to mean, but `std::wstring` is standard C++. You will not get any better in terms of interoperability than using the standard. As long as you get the ABI issues sorted out.