# Merging strings from txt files

Tags: c, string, file

The goal is to merge the strings from file1 and file2 but every time I try to do it only the first sentence of file 2 merges to file1. I don't understand why it's doing this and also I am new to programming and just started working with file pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]){

  FILE *fin1 = fopen(argv[1],"r");
  FILE *fin2 = fopen(argv[2],"r");

  FILE *fout = fopen(argv[3],"w");

  char sentence1[1000];
  char sentence2[500];

  fgets(sentence1,1000,fin1);
  fgets(sentence2,500,fin2);

  strcat(sentence1,sentence2);

  fprintf(fout,"%s",sentence1);

  printf("%s",sentence2);

  fclose(fin1);
  fclose(fin2);
  fclose(fout);

  return 0;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: No need for that `strcat()`, btw. Just use `fprintf(fout, "%s%s", sentence1, sentence2);`

Comment: You should include the resulting output file's contents too. You should be getting the *first* line of file2 in it, not the second.

Comment: Yes sorry only the first sentence is printing not the second. I removed the strcat() and it still doesn't work.

Comment: You have learned about loops, have you? Since you probably want to put `fgets` and `fprintf` in a loop. Calling `fgets` will only get you one line of input. To get the second line, you have to call `fgets` again.

Comment: [Please post your files as text, not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Thanks.

Comment: OT: never access beyond `argv[0]` with out first checking `argc` to assure the user actually entered the expected number of parameters.  Also, when the user did not enter the expected number of parameters, then output to `stderr` a USAGE message indicating the meaning of each command line parameter.  Suggest: `fprintf( stderr, "USAGE %s inputFile1 inputFile2 outputFile\n", argv[0] );`  followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: when calling `fopen()` (and most C library functions) always check for success.  If not successful, then call `perror( "your error message" );` Then clean up, then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Answer (score -1):

The `fgets` function stops parsing content when it reaches end-of-file or new lines. That's why it's only reading the first line of your files. You can check `fgets` full documentation [here](https://devdocs.io/c/io/fgets).

You may read every line of a file by looping through it while checking the result of `fgets`, for example:

```
char sentence[500] = "";
while (fgets(aux,sizeof(aux),fin) != NULL)
        strcat(sentence, aux);
```

Please note that this may not be the only solution and you can find other ideas [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25313850/c-how-do-i-read-all-lines-of-a-file).

Comment: Probably a better solution for this scenario would be to avoid the concatenation and `fprint` each line into `fout` separately, by the way.

Comment: `sentence` points to a read-only buffer of length 1. `strcat(sentence, aux)` will cause undefined behavior.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to add what would precede my code. I'll edit it.